# NameError: name 'new' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk

def factorialo():
    new = 1
    a = int(vvod.get())
    if a < 0:
        new = "Введите положительное число!"
    elif a == 0:
        exit()
    else:
        for i in range(1, a + 1):
            new = new * i
    return new

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title('Нахожедние факториала')
root.geometry("800x500")
print(root.geometry())

tkinter.Label(root, text="Нахождение факториала.").pack(pady=5)
tkinter.Label(root, text="Выход через ввод 0.").pack(pady=5)
vvod = tkinter.Entry(root, width=50, justify=tkinter.CENTER)
vvod.pack()
ttk.Button(root, text="Посчитать", command=factorialo).pack(pady=5)
tkinter.Label(root, text=new).pack(pady=20)

root.mainloop()
```

В общем сделал простой калькулятор факториала с UI на TkInter, при вводе в поле ввода и последующем нажатии на кнопку решения ниже должно выводить ответ, но выдаёт ошибку что якобы new не определено, если введу new = 1 до функции, то в ответе будет постоянно показана 1, помогите пожалуйста :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что переменная `new` у вас объявлена внутри функции `factorialo`, а значит является локальной переменной этой функции и неизвестной за ее пределами.

Поэтому ошибку неизвестной переменной вы видите именно при попытке работы с этой переменной из 26 строки, которая находится вне функции:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PythonCode.py", line 26, in <module>
    tkinter.Label(root, text=new).pack(pady=20)
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

NameError: name 'new' is not defined
```

Самый простой способ решить проблему — сделать переменную `new` глобальной, т.е. вынести ее за пределы функции. При этом, чтобы внутри функции переменная `new` не определялась как локальная переменная, ее нужно тоже пометить соответствующим образом (`global new`)

```py
new = 1

def factorialo():
    global new
    . . .

. . .
```

Comment: Not defined ушло, но теперь при нажатии кнопки "решить"  выводит ответ 1, как сделать вывод из функции? Return будто не возвращает

Comment: @StalkMg это уже тема другого вопроса, попробуйте разобраться самостоятельно, если не получится — задайте еще один вопрос. Если мой ответ решил вашу проблему, могу я попросить вас отметить его как решение?